# What am I doing wrong with the below implementation for problem : queens-attack-2 hackerrank?

Tags: java, algorithm

You will be given a square chess board with one queen and a number of obstacles placed on it. Determine how many squares the queen can attack.

Please find below my implementation.
Its working fine for many testcases but failing for few.
Am I missing any use case?
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;



class Point{
    int x;
    int y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Point() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
}
class Result { 
    public static void printBoard(int n, int k, int r_q, int c_q, List<List<Integer>> obstacles) {
        char[][] board = new char[n+1][n+1];
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)board[i][j]='.';
        board[r_q][c_q]='Q';
        for(List<Integer> o : obstacles) {
            int x = o.get(0);
            int y = o.get(1);
            board[x][y]='X';
        }
        for(int i=n;i>=1;i--) {
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    /*
     * n => row and column count in square board
     * k => number of obstacles
     * r_q => Queens row position 
     * c_q => Queens column position
     * obstacles => All obstacles position in (row, column) format
     * 
     */
    public static int queensAttack(int n, int k, int r_q, int c_q, List<List<Integer>> obstacles) {
//      printBoard(n,k,r_q,c_q,obstacles);
        
        /*
         * Board is like below
         *     |
         *  ^  |
         *  |  |
         *  |  |
         *  |  |
         * row |
         *index|
         *     |
         *     |_________________
         *         column index ---> 
         */
        
        //initiate last available blank position for all 8 terminal points
        
        Point 
            topLeft = r_q+c_q-1>n?new Point(n, r_q+c_q-n):new Point(r_q+c_q-1,1), 
            top = new Point(n,c_q), 
            topRight = r_q>c_q?new Point(n,n-(r_q-c_q)):new Point(n+(r_q-c_q),n),
            left = new Point(r_q,1),
            right = new Point(r_q,n), 
            bottomLeft = r_q>c_q?new Point(r_q-c_q+1,1):new Point(1,c_q-r_q+1), 
            bottom = new Point(1,c_q), 
            bottomRight = r_q+c_q-1>n?new Point(r_q+c_q-n,n):new Point(1,r_q+c_q-1);
            
            
            for(List<Integer> o : obstacles) {
                int x = o.get(0);
                int y = o.get(1);

                /*
                 * row==r_q would be horizontal line 
                 * left and right would be needed to update
                 * if obstacle is at (2,3) and queen at (2,9)
                 * then last available space on left side is (2,4)
                 * 
                 */
                if(x==r_q) {
                    if(y>=left.y && y<c_q) left.y=y+1;
                    if(y<=right.y && y>c_q) right.y=y-1;
                }
                /*
                 * col==c_q would be vertical line
                 * top and bottom would be needed to update
                 */
                if(y==c_q) {
                    if(x>=bottom.x && x<r_q) bottom.x=x+1;
                    if(x<=top.x && x>r_q)top.x=x-1;
                }
                /*
                 * row+col==r_q+c_q would be diagonal line from top left to bottom right
                 */
                if(x+y==r_q+c_q) {
                    if(y>=topLeft.y && y<c_q) {
                        topLeft.y=y+1;
                        topLeft.x=x-1;
                    }
                    if(y<=bottomRight.y && y>c_q) {
                        bottomRight.y=y-1;
                        bottomRight.x=x+1;
                    }
                }
                /*
                 * row-col==r_q-c_q would be diagonal line from top right to bottom left
                 */
                if(x-y==r_q-c_q) {
                    if(y>=bottomLeft.y && y<c_q) {
                        bottomLeft.y=y+1;
                        bottomLeft.x=x+1;
                    }
                    if(y<=topRight.y && y>c_q) {
                        topRight.y=y-1;
                        topLeft.x=x-1;
                    }
                }
            }
        
        /*
         * if in any line (x,y) is last available space and 
         * queen is at (r_q,c_q), then number of places queen can attack is 
         * |r_q-x| or |c_q-y| both would necessarily be equal
         * so I am using any one of them
         */
        return 
            (topLeft.x-r_q) +
            (top.x-r_q) +
            (topRight.x-r_q)+
            (c_q-left.y)+
            (right.y-c_q)+
            (c_q-bottomLeft.y)+
            (r_q-bottom.x)+
            (r_q-bottomRight.x);
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("INPUT.txt")));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OUTPUT.txt"));
        String[] firstMultipleInput = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(firstMultipleInput[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(firstMultipleInput[1]);
        String[] secondMultipleInput = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");
        int r_q = Integer.parseInt(secondMultipleInput[0]);
        int c_q = Integer.parseInt(secondMultipleInput[1]);
        List<List<Integer>> obstacles = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, k).forEach(i -> {
            try {
                obstacles.add(
                    Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .collect(toList())
                );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
        int result = Result.queensAttack(n, k, r_q, c_q, obstacles);
        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Input file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yFPAIkW4o-Zf3fwf5o_qK-_ckZWLEAr0/view?usp=share_link
My Output : 190709
Expected Output : 110198

Comment: please provide some comments in your code, it's really hard to follow. Explain how your trying to resolve the problem. I would also strongly advise that you use 0 indexed board, as this diminish the risk of `of-by-one` errors.

Comment: @AloisChristen 
Thanks for help. I have updated comments. 
Regarding index, here I am preferring 1-index as thats how obstacles index is given.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a look. Even if obstacle is 1-indexed, java is a 0-indexed language, so I would transform the input right after read, use 0-indexed in the program logic, and then transform back in output. There is so much potential for error right there, and 0-indexed math is way easier.

Comment: Hint: diagonal is not working correctly - try a 2x2 square, queen at 1,1 and one obstacle at 2,2

Comment: ah, thanks a lot @user16320675. I see my mistake.
Edit :: All test cases passed. Thanks again to both user16320675 and Alois Christen